# TabBarView inside column is giving me error in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to have Column with a Container at the top, followed by TabBar and TabBarView.
But I got this error message:

> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#b4962 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
>   'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1687
>   pos 12: 'hasSize' The relevant error-causing widget was
>       Column

These are my code:

```
TabController _tabController;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _tabController = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
}

return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFec6647),
        body: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.125,
                  child: FittedBox(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03),
                        Text('TITLE TEXT'),
                        SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )),
              TabBar(
                controller: _tabController,
                tabs: [
                  Tab(child: Text('Login')),
                  Tab(child: Text('Register')),
                ],
              ),
              TabBarView(
                controller: _tabController,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                  Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Try wrapping your `TabBarView` in an `Expanded` widget.

Comment: @SupposedlySam it works. Thanks! Can you please explain why this works and previous one doesn't?

Comment: The `Column` widget tries to get its height from it's children. If a child specifying its height as infinite, aka unbounded, or "as much as possible", and is added to the list of children, the `Column` isn't able to calculate its height and an error results. Using the `Expanded` widget allows the column to understand that you want this child to take up "as much space as possible" bounded by the parent of the `Column`, which is usually the height of the app, or body of the `Scaffold` or something similar.

Comment: understood. Thanks @SupposedlySam!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer by SupposedlySam works, which is to wrap the TabBarView in an Expanded widget.